# Do you have to have a Holy Symbol in one of your hands to use it?

Tags: dnd-4e, cleric, holy-symbol

Do you have to have a `Holy Symbol` in one of your hands to use it ... (a) in your attacks, (b) to gain advantage of any special effects ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**,

A character does not need to hold a Holy Symbol in his or her hands to benefit from it in any way.

From the *Rules Compendium* pg274

> Unlike other implements, a holy symbol can be used whether it is worn or held.  If a creature wears or holds more than one holy symbol, none of these symbols function until only one remains (this rule is usually relevant only to magic holy symbols).

Comment: does the compendium say whether the holy symbol must be visibly displayed when worn, or can it be worn under clothing/armor?

Comment: @SteveED - nothing directly on point no.  I don't think there is any obvious benefit one way or the other.

Comment: @SteveED that's really a question for your DM and not a rulebook.

Comment: @DreadGazebo - actually I always thought the cleric had to forcefully display the holy symbol in one of his hands to gain it's benefits, so I'm glad this question came up.